# How to setup Apache httpd server for multiple domain with Self Sign openssl certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have one development server ( Apache httpd) which is having multiple domains:

```
abc_xyz.domain1.com
abc_xyz.domain2.com
```

As of now only one self singed Openssl certificate i have installed for "abc_xyz.domain1.com".
Now i want to host both my domain on the same server with Self Sign Openssl Certificate, as it's our own development environment where we no need paid SSL.

I have tried with below options but no luck:-

```
- Installed separate SSL certificate for both domain with virtual host (as wildcard certificate i don't think will be applied for my case)
- tried pointing same certificate for both domain
```

If anyone can guide here, it would be a great help.

Comment: Have successfully setup multiple domain by following below steps:-

Comment: - loaded both the certificate and virtual host entries in ssl.conf file.